# Filter GridView with SqlDataSource, DropDownLists not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I made a search function in gridview format. I have 1 textbox, 2 dropdownlist and a search button. My textbox is use to search the lastname of a doctor, the 1st and 2nd dropdown is use to filter which province or city they belong and a search button to execute.

The textbox is working, when I search for a doctor's lastname, but the dropdowns are not.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
              AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
              BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOCTOR_FIRSTNAME" HeaderText="DOCTOR_FIRSTNAME" 
                 SortExpression="DOCTOR_FIRSTNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOCTOR_MI" HeaderText="DOCTOR_MI" 
                 SortExpression="DOCTOR_MI" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOCTOR_LASTNAME" HeaderText="DOCTOR_LASTNAME" 
                 SortExpression="DOCTOR_LASTNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ROOM" HeaderText="ROOM" SortExpression="ROOM" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SCHEDULE" HeaderText="SCHEDULE" 
                 SortExpression="SCHEDULE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SPECIALIZATION" HeaderText="SPECIALIZATION" 
                 SortExpression="SPECIALIZATION" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROVINCE_NAME" HeaderText="PROVINCE_NAME" 
                 SortExpression="PROVINCE_NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CITY_NAME" HeaderText="CITY_NAME" 
                 SortExpression="CITY_NAME" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicolConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT 
            emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_FIRSTNAME, 
            emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_MI, 
            emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_LASTNAME, 
            emed_doctors_hospitals.ROOM, 
            emed_doctors_hospitals.SCHEDULE, 
            emed_accredited_providers.SPECIALIZATION, 
            emed_province.PROVINCE_NAME, 
            emed_city.CITY_NAME FROM emed_city 
            INNER JOIN emed_province ON emed_city.PROVINCE_CODE = 
            emed_province.PROVINCE_CODE INNER JOIN 
            emed_doctors_hospitals ON emed_city.CITY_CODE = 
            emed_doctors_hospitals.CITY_CODE INNER JOIN 
            emed_accredited_providers ON 
            emed_doctors_hospitals.DOCTOR_CODE = 
            emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_CODE WHERE 
            (emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_LASTNAME LIKE '%' + 
            @DOCTOR_LASTNAME + '%') OR 
            (emed_doctors_hospitals.PROVINCE_CODE = @PROVINCE_CODE) 
            ORDER BY emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_FIRSTNAME"
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" 
                Name="DOCTOR_LASTNAME" 
                PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" 
                Name="PROVINCE_CODE" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="PROVINCE_NAME" 
        DataValueField="PROVINCE_NAME">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicolConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PROVINCE_NAME] FROM [emed_province] ORDER BY [PROVINCE_NAME] ASC">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
```

Comment: Would need to see what you are doing on the drop down events. (c# code) - Basically you need to change the data source based on the filters and textbox, if text box has data and the drop downs dont, then use this data source, otherwise if textbox and both drop downs use this other etc..

Comment: i have no code in my .cs files. i put it all inside .aspx. i just bind the values for the 1st dropdown. that's all. i think the problem is my query or something.

EDIT: so meaning i have to change the datasource of my dropdown and use the datasource i used for the gridview?

Comment: No you need c# code because you need to tell the server which data source to use depending on the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataValueField=PROVINCE_CODE`, as you are using that value from the dropdownlist in the `where` clause to fetch the record.

Presently, `PROVINCE_NAME` is going to the search query, instead of `PROVINCE_CODE`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="PROVINCE_NAME"  
        DataValueField="PROVINCE_NAME">
```

Use this instead of the above one:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="PROVINCE_NAME"  
        DataValueField="PROVINCE_CODE">
```

Also, you need to fetch `[PROVINCE_CODE]` from the table to bind it to the dropdownlist.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"  
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicolConnectionString %>"  
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PROVINCE_CODE],[PROVINCE_NAME] FROM [emed_province] ORDER BY [PROVINCE_NAME] ASC">
```